# Is there a more elegant way to calculate x = (y / n) + (y % n ? 1 : 0) ?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

While programming I often find myself needing to calculate something like:

`x = (y / n) + (y % n ? 1 : 0);`

Or more explicitly:

```
x = y / n;
if (y % n != 0) {
   x = x + 1;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this value? Can it be achieved without using a conditional expression?

Comment: Is y or n ever negative? In your model, does integer division round towards zero, or round towards negative infinity?

Comment: @Kevin: y and n are always positive. Technically I guess it truncates, which would be towards zero.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, you want the integer division to round up instead of down. You can fake this by adding `n-1` to the numerator:

```
x = (y + n - 1) / n;
```

That way you shift the value it'll be rounded down to just enough to give you the desired outcome.

Comment: Just be aware of possible overflow/wrapping issues if `n` or `y` is large.